# Unable to merge these sql queries into one query

Tags: mysql, join

First Query:

```
select * 
from PLAYERS_DATA pd,PLAYERS_SERVICE ps 
where pd.ID=ps.ID
```

Second Query:

```
select * 
from PLAYERS p, PLAYERS_SERVICE ps 
where p.PLAYER_ID=ps.PLAYER_ID
```

Third Query:

```
select * 
from PLAYERS_PROPERTY pp, PLAYERS p 
where pp.PLAYER_ID=p.PLAYER_ID
```

My Attempt to join these 3 queries:

```
select distinct p.*,pp.*,pd.*
from PLAYERS p
    join PLAYERS_SERVICE ps on p.PLAYER_ID=ps.PLAYER_ID
    join PLAYERS_DATA pd on pd.ID=ps.ID
    join PLAYERS_PROPERTY pp on pp.PLAYER_ID=p.PLAYER_ID
```

With my query, the relation looks fine, but I am seeing duplicate records when I included different columns from different tables in select query. While I was using distinct also, able to see duplicate records. Can anyone please help me to identify the mistake and get matching distinct records for columns from different tables.

Comment: Didnt you ask this once today already

Comment: Your second query isn't even valid syntax. `AND` should be `JOIN`, and `WHERE` should be `ON`.

Comment: You can't get duplicates if you use `DISTINCT`. One of the tables you're joining with must have multiple matching rows with different values.

Comment: Please post sample data and desired results.

Comment: *but I am seeing duplicate records* In SQL the term "duplicate records" means "two rows where absolutely all columns contains absolutely the same value which is not NULL". If at least one column values differs, or at least one NULL is present, then these rows are NOT duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use the `DISTINCT` keyword, it is impossible to receive duplicate records. It is possible that there are partial duplicates (like a service having multiple data matches and property matches).

However, you also have duplicate fields if the same field is represented in multiple tables. To avoid duplicating your fields, it is a good idea to not select everything like

```
select distinct p.*,pp.*,pd.*
```

because it is unsafe (what if there is a password or other sensitive data that is unnecessary to your result) and superfluous (loading unnecessary fields), as well as increases resource usage, as all the unnecessary fields for all your records are loaded into memory without a need for it, which also drops performance.

You should list the exact columns you need instead of selecting everything from everything.

After you fix your fields, your `DISTINCT` might become more effective. If it's still not enough, then you will need to modify your join/where criteria according to your needs. If you need further information, then you need to provide:

- which columns you need from which tables
- sample data which reproduces the issue
- explaining through an example or a pattern how the undesired duplicate manifests in your case

A SQL fiddle would not hurt either.